# How to use Method level validation

Tags: spring, validation

I'm trying to validate some parameters used in a method with javax.validation, but I'm having trouble doing it right.

This is my method:

```
ServiceResponseInterface getEngineTriage(
            @NotNull(message = Constants.MANDATORY_PARAMETERS_MISSING) String riskAssessmentId,
            @NotNull(message = Constants.MANDATORY_PARAMETERS_MISSING) String participantId,
            @Pattern(regexp = "NEW|RENEWAL|EDIT|OPERATION|RATING", flags = Pattern.Flag.CASE_INSENSITIVE, message = Constants.WRONG_PARAMETERS) String eventType) {

                ~Some code~ 
                return ServiceResponseNoContent.ServiceResponseNoContentBuilder.build();
            }
```

The class has the @Validated annotation, at this point I'm stuck, how can I check when I call the method if the paramethers are validated?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if your configuration is right, your method is not executed if any validation error occurs. So you need to handle your method with a simple try-catch block.

I will give an example configuration for method level validation in Spring below.

```java
public interface IValidationService {

    public boolean methodLevelValidation(@NotNull String param);

}
```

```java
@Service
@Validated
public class ValidationService implements IValidationService {

    @Override
    public boolean methodLevelValidation(String param) {
        // some business logic here
        return true;
    }

}
```

And you can handle any validation errors like below:

```java
@Test
public void testMethodLevelValidationNotPassAndHandle() {

    boolean result = false;
    try {
        result = validationService.methodLevelValidation(null);
        Assert.assertTrue(result);
    } catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
        Assert.assertFalse(result);
        Assert.assertNotNull(e.getMessage());
        logger.info(e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

**Note:** You need to define your validation annotations in your interface if you have implemented your component from one. Otherwise, you can just put it in your bare spring component:

```java
@Component
@Validated
public class BareValidationService {

    public boolean methodLevelValidation(@NotNull String param) {

        return true;
    }

}
```

Hope this helps, cheers!